# Select an evenly distributed records in a SQL table for a set of users from a second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, round-robin

I have a large table in SQL Server with user activity (Table A) and another table with list of users (Table B).

I need to run through the activity table and do a serialized selection of each user, and put the new records into a third table (Table C).

In other words, for each user in Table B, I need to get 1 matching record from Table A, and put them into a new table C, and the repeat the whole process until everyone gets x number of records each.

The end result is so that I can get a distributed record set in Table C, where each user is equally represented.

Comment: Define: "large table" - are we talking millions or billions or tens of billions of rows?

Comment: What is a "serialized selection"?  Please define "evenly distributed"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Also, design-tip: RDBMS is not a good choice to store user-activity logs owing to the _relatively_ high cost of inserting rows with foreign-key constraints (and because most Cloud RDBMS providers charge significantly more for RDBMS than _dumb_ storage, e.g. Azure SQL vs. Azure Table Storage or an Append-blob store).

Comment: What options have you researched and considered? What have you tried?

Comment: Evenly distributed as in I want to make sure that the users gets evenly selected.  I don't want to end up with some users being selected more than the others.  For example, I want to select 100 records from the thousands of activity records, I want to make sure each of the users are selected fairly. I am looking for users 1, 2, 3... 1, 2, 3... and so on.  I understand it might still be off if some users have less activity than others, but it would be better than ending up with 80 for one user and 10 each for the other two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions or a lateral join.  Let's do the lateral join.  If you want a *random selection* of  records for each user:

```
select a.*
from b cross apply
     (select top (x) a.*
      from a
      where a.user_id = b.user_id
      order by newid()
     ) a;
```

Of course, if there aren't enough records in `a`, then some users will have fewer records.

Comment: @Dai . . . `rand()` won't give a random distribution at all because it is constant in the query.

Comment: This is good, but if I do top 3, it will give me the results grouped by the users like 111, 222, etc.  I was looking for 123, 123.

Comment: @John . . . If you want the results in a particular order, you need to add an `order by` to the outer query.